# How can i explode group_concat and display individually

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have used  group_concat to Merge the following table records of the same column, 
But how can i `explode` and display individually as an array.

Thank you

//Table A

```
  Customer ID     Customer_Bill_Name.......                  
    XXX001           XXX Company Name......           
    XXX002           YYY Company Name......
```

//Table B

```
 Customer ID          Item ID 1           
     XXX001            WH15 02
     XXX001            600278        
     XX0002            600000
```

This join all values to one column.

```
select a.*, group_concat(b.ItemId) joined
from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.customerId = b.customerId
group by a.customerId, a.customer, a.company
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMERID  CUSTOMER    COMPANY         JOINED
XXX001      XXX         Company Name    600278,WH15 02
XXX002      YYY         Company Name    600000
```

//Finally Table C: I want to end up like this

```
  Customer ID     Customer_Bill_Name       Item ID 1            Item ID 2           
    XXX001         XXX Company Name         WH15 02             600278 
    XX0002         YYY Company Name         600000
```

Comment: group_concat by default joins the values with a comma. What's the problem with using `explode(',',$r);`, assuming `$r` the value of the group_concat column?

Comment: Um, don't group_concat the result

Comment: both the above ideas are great. but if you showed the actual desired result some one could provide more details

Comment: @Sebas @Dagon thanks is this the right way to do it or how can i put `group_concat(b.ItemId)` in the variable outside select statement `$test= group_concat(b.ItemId)`; then `explode(',',$test)`

Comment: @Hulu an ungrouped mysql result is an array. It can be ordered. PHP loves arrays. Especially ordered arrays

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks! please take a look at the table at the bottom of my question. That is why i want to explode and extract each value as $test[1], $test[2], but i am not sure how to store `group_concat(b.ItemId)` in some variable. I tried this `$test= group_concat(b.ItemId)` but no luck

Comment: Yes, that would be a simple PHP loop on an ungrouped, but ordered, mysql result.